# Send me email everytime a certain file is accessed from my apache server

Tags: linux, apache, bash, email, logging

I want to have my server send me an email every time someone accesses a PDF file on my webserver.

Perhaps:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache.log | grep pdf > ??something??
```

How would I generate a new email message each time this `tail/grep` outputs something? How could I have that running as a `background process`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit crude, but would do the job. Save the file and execute it with `./name.sh &` to put it in the background

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/path/to/your/file
TERM="pdf"

while read line; do
        echo $line | grep $TERM > /dev/null && echo "your mail body"  | mail -s "new $TERM access" you@somewhere.com
done < <(tail -1f $FILE)
```

However, I wouldn't necessarily recommend using this sort of approach. If you want something to be triggered each time a file is accessed in apache, you might be able to write a small cgi program to handle your actions and return the file. I would suggest investigation of the `AddHandler` directive as described here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/handler.html.

Comment: This is working. Thanks! What's the best way to execute the `./name.sh &` automatically each time the system boots up so I don't have to do it manually if I reboot?

Comment: Look at how Apache is being started up, maybe hook into that. This is somewhat distro-dependent. On Debian/Ubuntu, you can add stuff to `rc.local` but it might run before Apache (haven't checked).

Answer (score 0):

1)Install `File Tail perl module`
take cpan from console by typing `cpan`

```
cpan>install File::Tail
```

2)save this code as `logscan.pl` .Edit $name variable and save correct log name in it and run as `perl logscan.pl &`

The `&` sign tells the script to run in background.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
  use File::Tail;
  $name = '/var/log/apache.log';
  $file=File::Tail->new(name=>$name, maxinterval=>300, adjustafter=>7);
  while (defined($line=$file->read)) {

     if($line =~ m/pdf/gi){

           $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
           $subject = 'the subject';
           $message = 'hello';
           mail($to, $subject, $message);    
     }
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error and don't know perl to debug.  Is there a typo?

`syntax error at logscan.pl line 7, near "$line ~"`